# Split string multiple patterns

Tags: java, regex, string, string-parsing

I have a string of form `"Some lengthy string, Pattern1: string1, Pattern2: string2, Pattern3: string3"`. My objective is to extract `string1`, `string2` and `string3` from such a `String`.

Note that the `Strings`, `Pattern1`, `Pattern2` and `Pattern3` themselves consist of multiple characters. I know the solution if these patterns were single characters. Currently I am forced to do multiple `String.split()` calls one each for `Pattern1`, `Pattern2` and `Pattern3`.

Is there a more graceful way of doing this? Or there is no escaping multiple `split()` calls?

EDIT: I was looking or a java specific solution (Hence Java was in title, but it got edited out). Any way. This is what I tried and it appears to work for me.

```
String someString = "Some lengthy string Pattern1: string1 Pattern2: string2 Pattern3: string3";
String [] str = someString.split("Pattern1:|Pattern2:|Pattern3:");
System.out.println(str[1]);
System.out.println(str[2]);
System.out.println(str[3]);
```

Output of this is

```
string1
string2
string3
```

Any obvious problems with this?

Comment: Capturing groups may help: [`(?s)Pattern1:\s*(.*?),\s*Pattern2:\s*(.*?),\s*Pattern3:\s*(.*)"`](https://regex101.com/r/LA4cts/2)

Answer (score 1):

To get an array of your targets, you first must strip off the leading part, then split on the other patterns:

```
String targets = input.replaceAll("^.*?Pattern1: ", "").split(", (Pattern2|Pattern3): ");
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a String.replaceAll() instead with capture groups?

```
str.replaceAll(".*(?:Pattern1: ([^,]*))(?:, Pattern2: ([^,]*))(?:, Pattern3: ([^,]*))", "$1;$2;$3").split(";");
```

or to make it even shorter, you can remove the patterns and just look for the colons:

```
str.replaceAll("[^:]*: ([^,]*,?)", "$1").split(",");
```

Comment: I like this, but consider changing it to: `..., "$1;$2;$3").split(";")` to get an array instead of onecontinuousstring

Comment: Modified. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

String stringToSearch = "Some lengthy string Pattern1: string1 Pattern2: string2 Pattern3: string3";

```
String REGEX = "Pattern\\w:\\s[\\w]+";
Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile(REGEX);
Matcher m = p1.matcher(stringToSearch);

Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile(":");

while (m.find())
{
    String[] items = p2.split(m.group());
    if(items.length < 2 )
       break;
    System.out.println(items[1]);   
}
```

Output:

string1
string2
string3